# Google Docs / Drawing

Tags: google-drive

I'm looking into creating a Google Docs "drawing" for the purpose of creating a basic UML diagram (without arrows, just lines) while collaborating with others. The problem I am having is that I can create

- a box without text (shapes/box_image from dropdown menu)
- text without a box (from the 'text box' menu (perhaps a misnomer))

However, I need text with a box.

If this is not possible with Google Docs, I would consider another collaborative method for creating UML diagrams. Google Docs is really best though because we already share many Google documents.

Comment: If your problem has now been resolved, please don't forget to assign the bounty amount to the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Barry. I was under the false impression that by selecting an answer the bounty was automatically awarded. I believe I just awarded it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to Google Docs
2. Click **Create**
3. Choose **Drawing**
4. Click on the **Shape** icon
5. Choose your shape
   [image]
6. Draw your shape
7. Click right on your shape
8. Click **Edit text...**
   [image]
9. Enter your text
   [image]
10. Click **Enter**
    [image]

Answer (score 0):

Double click on your shape and a text box will pop up. You can enter text in that box that shows on the shape after you click off it.

Answer (score 0):

We have an [example](http://drive.diagram.ly/) of our developer library that integrates with drive (was docs) and has UML support. It's not commercial and there's no support, but people seem to be using it happily enough.